# Apache 2.2 403 Forbidden when accessing .sh file

Tags: linux, bash, apache, .htaccess

My linux apache 2.2 server is giving a 403 when serving a `.sh` script file.  The file is intended to be downloaded and linked to via a simple href:

```
<a href="http://www.myserver.com/downloads/test.sh">Click to Download</a>
```

Clicking yields a 403.

The apache error log displays:

> ==> mysever.com-error_log <==
>   [Fri Dec 18 20:04:29 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/downloads/test.sh, referer: http://www.myserver.com/downloads/test.html

If I copy the file to one with a different extension even like `.exe` it lets me download it.  So it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.

I tried changing how apache treats the file by adding to `httpd.conf` and a `.htaccess` in the same directory:

```
AddType text/plain .sh
```

No luck.

I tried with no luck adding these options to the apache directory

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

Very weird.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that ModSecurity is blocking the request because of the .sh extension.

You can also try adding the following to your .htaccess:

```
<Files  ~ "\.sh$">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.   This solves my problem.  Have a great night!